# Cannot use libsvm in weka 3.7.10 after install it from weka package manager, on Windows

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

guys

I installed weka 3.7.10 (with jre1.7 included), and installed libsvm via its package manager.

But when I use Explorer to open the data and try to choose a classifier, I found the "libSVM" under "classifiers -> functions" is grey and not usable (It chooseable actually, but when I choose it, the start button is disabled)

I checked the folder of the downloaded packages, and I can see the libsvm.jar in "C:\Users\qsmile\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\lib".

So I add "C:\Users\qsmile\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\lib\libsvm.jar" to the CLASSPATH environment variables, which is now ".;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;C:\Users\qsmile\wekafiles\packages\LibSVM\lib\libsvm.jar", but it does not work.

And I edited the "RunWeka.ini" file under the weka installed directory, and modified the last line into "cp=%CLASSPATH%;C:\\Users\\qsmile\\wekafiles\\packages\\LibSVM\\lib\\libsvm.jar". This change is according to the trouble shooting part on http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM. After that, when use "java weka.core.SystemInfo" command to test, I can see the property java.class.path correctly shows the libsvm.jar in the right path. But, when I try to choose libsvm among classifiers, it is still grey and does not work.

So, can anybody help me figure this out? Thanks a lot a lot a lot!

My OS: Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Have you tried different datasets in case your original is not compatible with the method?  The example weather data provided with Weka should work, if it was installed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just installed both LibSVM and LibLinear on Windows 7 x64 using the package manager and it works for me.

Both LibLinear and LibSVM are grayed out when the dataset contains missing values. Did you try with a simple dataset not having any missing values like for example the Iris dataset?

Comment: Missing values or rogue string values that should be numeric are the key to getting all the classifiers and attribute selectors to show up correctly.  I was having the same problem.  Thanks !    In some ways its annoying that version 3.6 would let you play with rubbish data, however its probably best that 3.7 and 3.8 alert you to this by not allowing you to proceed.